# Including stylesheet in <head> gives different result than javascript append to head

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, stylesheet

Using HTML5 and jQuery, I would like to implement JPlayer (from www.jplayer.org).

Unfortunately, I cannot make it work the way I would like. In the end, my problem seems to be an issue of stylesheet "inclusion". For some reason I do not understand, the stylesheet does not work properly when using "jQuery appendTo head" instead of a "html link". The file is definetely included but the GUI is messed up when firing a javascript action.

I have attached both examples which can be used anywhere for testing. I made comments on the only lines which are different.

**Here is the first file. This example is working as expected:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test with link rel</title>

    <!-- ONLY DIFFERENCE IS THIS LINE -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jplayer.org/latest/skin/blue.monday/jplayer.blue.monday.css" />
    <!-- END -->

</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>

<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>

<div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
        <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
            <ul class="jp-controls">
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="jp-progress">
                <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                    <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-time-holder">
                <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                <div class="jp-duration"></div>

                <ul class="jp-toggles">
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-title">
            <ul>
                <li>Cro Magnon Man</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-no-solution">
            <span>Update Required</span>
            To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({ready: function (event) {$(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {m4a:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.m4a"});},supplied: "m4a",wmode: "window",smoothPlayBar: true,keyEnabled: true});
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

**The second file which is not properly working:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test with jquery appendTo</title>
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>

<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>

<div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
        <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
            <ul class="jp-controls">
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="jp-progress">
                <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                    <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-time-holder">
                <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                <div class="jp-duration"></div>

                <ul class="jp-toggles">
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-title">
            <ul>
                <li>Cro Magnon Man</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-no-solution">
            <span>Update Required</span>
            To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- ONLY DIFFERENCE IS THES LINES -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({ready: function (event) {$(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {m4a:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.m4a"});},supplied: "m4a",wmode: "window",smoothPlayBar: true,keyEnabled: true});
    $('<link>', { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: 'http://www.jplayer.org/latest/skin/blue.monday/jplayer.blue.monday.css' }).appendTo('head');
</script>
<!-- END -->

</body>

</html>
```

The stylesheet IS working on the second file, but as soon as you click something on the player, the GUI is messed up. Why is that? Could I make some changes to the provided jPlayer stylesheets to make it work with my second example?

Comment: "I have attached both examples which can be used anywhere for testing." Why then not providing jsFiddle links???

Comment: Because in jsFiddle I cannot include the whole html at once which I found useful in this case?

Comment: May be the jPlayer css is overriding your custom css. Try to dig into the jPlayer css to know more.

Comment: Not possible because all custom JS and CSS is excluded from the examples I gave

Comment: You should just try to append (or prepend) link tag before initializing jPlayer. BTW, you could initialize jPlayer inside LINK onload callback, just in case...

Comment: @A.Wolff You should submit that as an answer -- seems to solve the problems for me.

Comment: @A.Wolff switching the "append" and the "init jPlayer" did not solve the problem for me. Maybe you could provide your idea as an answer if it works for you?

Comment: i tried running the second (problematic) html on my system. and i noticed the issues you were talking about. and i found some weirdness. for example, when clicking on the play button, it shows the text pause, with the button image as a background and that the style for that element was `display:inline` and not `display:block` which was how it was being set in the first html. i checked the code but couldn't find anywhere where they were setting an element's css as `display:inline`. this is by far the craziest thing i have ever seen

Comment: It is probably done in their javascript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should fix your issue, calling plugin once CSS file is loaded:

```
$('<link>', {
    rel: 'stylesheet',
    type: 'text/css',
    href: 'http://www.jplayer.org/latest/skin/blue.monday/jplayer.blue.monday.css'
}).one('load', function () {
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
        ready: function (event) {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                m4a: "http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.m4a"
            });
        },
        supplied: "m4a",
        wmode: "window",
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true
    });
}).appendTo('head');
```

Although, this could be enough in most cases:

```
$('<link>', { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: 'http://www.jplayer.org/latest/skin/blue.monday/jplayer.blue.monday.css' }).appendTo('head');
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({ready: function (event) {$(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {m4a:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.m4a"});},supplied: "m4a",wmode: "window",smoothPlayBar: true,keyEnabled: true});
```

Comment: First example works, great. Do you know why it has to be this way? The second example does not work for me in FF and Chrome even if it looks valid to me...

Comment: @andreas i guess plugin internal code is using some specific CSS values to be correctly settled. I don't know this plugin so I'm just guessing. And using onload, you are sure CSS file is loaded and so CSS rules are applied. Appending script/link after document is ready, making it async